# How to get Excel VBA code to trigger Word Mail Merge

Tags: excel, vba, mailmerge

I have an Excel file that is used to populate a Word document via mail merge.
When I open the Word document, it reacts properly and a Message Box appears stating:
[image]
PERFECT!!

But, when I created a button in Excel to open this Word Document, I cannot get it to trigger the Mail Merge.

Here is the code in my Excel document for the button I've created.

```
Private Sub cmbPrintWarranty_Click()

    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    ' Get the Word application
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WordApp = GetObject(Class:="Word.Application")
    If WordApp Is Nothing Then
        Set WordApp = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    WordApp.Visible = True
    ' Get the active document
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open _
        ("C:\Users\User1\OneDrive - User1\Documents\Projects Open\zzWarranty.docx")

End Sub
```

That code opens the document, but I just get the original data, no update or trigger to update with mail merge.

What do I need to change here?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Does your word document you open with your code contain that macro which throws the message you've shown in your post?

Comment: Maybe just open Word document with Shell command instead of manipulating Word objects. Or if you want to skip the prompt, review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442030/running-a-ms-word-mail-merge-from-excel

Comment: @June7 That does seem to work.  The only issue is that the 'dialog' box that asks do I want to merge DOES NOT come into focus.  So, windows sounds the 'attention' signal, but the user doesn't see what to do.  
How can I force Excel to loose focus or pull Word into focus?

Comment: What worked - Shell command or code from the referenced link? I have no idea how to change app focus. Sounds like issue I had with Access and Excel and part of reason I eliminated Excel from the process. It was a partially built database I inherited and it used Excel for data entry and output while just storing in Access. The user would start in Access presenting menu choices which opened Excel but it opened behind Access. Very annoying and I could not resolve. My question to you is why are you using Excel? Could Access be better and eliminate both Excel and Word?

Comment: 'Private Sub cmbMM_Click()
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    ' Get the Word application
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WordApp = GetObject(Class:="Word.Application")
    If WordApp Is Nothing Then
       Set WordApp = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    WordApp.Visible = True
    
    Set wdDoc = GetObject("G:\My Drive\Congregation\PT Coordinator\LetterIncomingInvite.docx", "Word.document")
    wdDoc.Application.Visible = True
End Sub'

Comment: That is the code I have so far.  which I cannot format properly.   And that code does NOT bring into focus WORD

Comment: I haven't used Access in a long while.  I've become so comfortable with Excel, but maybe I need to dust off those skills and get back into Access.