How do I get my Mailmerge VBA routine not to show dialog box and to run automatically
I am using Office 2016 to try and automatically send emails using VBA.
The routines export 1 record at a time to a spreadsheet and the Word mailmerge is invoked using the spreadsheet.
The Word document is then saved as a PDF and the email sent containing the PDF.
The problem I am having is that the routine keeps producing the same dialog box for every record and I would like it to run automatically.
The error I am getting is
Dialog box
The code I am using is
acExport, _ 
acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _ 
"Updatedetailsone", _ 
mailmergexls, True 

' 
' Merge Word document with mailmerge spreadsheet file 
' 

Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 
wordApp.Visible = True 

Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(mailmergedoc) 
With wordDoc.MailMerge 
  .MainDocumentType = wdMailingLetters 
  .OpenDataSource Name:=mailmergexls, _ 
  ConfirmConversions:=False, _ 
  ReadOnly:=False, _ 
  LinkToSource:=False, _ 
  AddToRecentFiles:=False, _ 
  Connection:="Updatedetailsone" 
  .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument 
  .Execute 
  .MainDocumentType = wdNotAMergeDocument 
End With 

' 
' Delete existing membership form PDF file 
' Create new membership form PDF file with current record 
' 

Kill mailmergepdf 

wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 mailmergepdf, 17 
' 
' Close and clean up Word documents 
' 
For Each wordDoc In wordApp.Documents 
  wordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False 
  Next wordDoc 
wordApp.Quit 

Set wordDoc = Nothing 
Set wordApp = Nothing

Any help will be appreciated.
I would like the routine to automatically select the 1st table without prompting.

Please don't post images of whole screen. Consider that readers might be using phones or tablets. Always post error messages as text, so they can be searched for. What is the error message?

Why not Word merge from Access? Why not Access report instead of Word? Maybe use an SQL statement - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442030/running-a-ms-word-mail-merge-from-excel and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585226/automating-mail-merge-using-excel-vba

In OpenDataSource, You just need the *full path name of the excel file in the Name parameter, and an SQLStatement parameter that will be something like "SELECT * FROM [Updatedetailsone$]" . (The connection paprameter is wrong, and you shouldn't need it anyway with modern versions of word). Just make sure you don't save your mail merge main document with the connection info.

Are you able to advise whether it would be better mailmerging from an access table or exporting the data to an xlsx file and merging from there?

My view is it's always preferable to keep a process within a single app if possible. I would consider merging with Word only if Access report could not generate desired output. And then why would Excel need to be involved?

The process I have written (1) makes a table of the records I want to process, (2) moves the 1st record to a new table, (3) exports that record to a spreadsheet, (4) mailmerges the record in the spreadsheet, creates a pdf of the mailmerge doc, (5) emails the pdf, (6) repeats from (2) until eof

I am a VBA beginner so would appreciate it if I could email my code to someone who would look at it and suggest better ways of doing it.

So far, haven't given me any information that justifies even using Word merge much less involving Excel. Could post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide yours for analysis.

New members complete a 5 page form and the details are stored in the database. Every year I want to send them a pdf file containing their current information. They can reply with any changes.

The pdf file is in exactly the same format as the form they originally filled in.

Doesn't alter my previous comment.

So what would your advice be on the best way to do it

I would suggest it depends on a combination of "who's going to be using it", "who's going to be maintaining it, "how well you know each tool", "whether it is in fact possible to get the layout you want in (say) an Access report" and the cost (time/resources/support hassle) involved in (a) getting it right and (b) getting it wrong.  If you can do it all in Access, there's certainly a lot less to go wrong! But it should be possible to avoid Excel even if you have to use Word (e.g. in Access, create a table and put one record in it. then specify that table as your Word data source)..

I originally meant to say more about how you can connect directly to an Access table from a Word mail merge main document.
It's not straightforward, because when you are developing, Word often reports that it can't connect to the data because someone has put the database into a certain state.  One thing that causes that is any change to a VBA module, which means that you have to save the database before testing any change you make in the code (and although you would probably know if you were using a 3rd party VB Editor addin, be aware that they can also make changes "behind the scenes"). Access will try to "promote" a lock to "Exclusive" primarily to ensure that design changes are not blocked when you try to save the change - for further info., see e.g. this
I also find that when you update table data in Access VBA in the CurrentDB, Access tends to lock stuff. It might be possible to work around that by  using a connection file in your Word .OpenDataSource call that specifies a suitable open option (shared read only or something like that). However, another way to avoid that problem is to create a table in a different .accdb file and use that as your data source. So the following code is my suggestion for how you can do that to avoid going via Excel.
This part doesn't cover the bit where you automate Outlook, but perhaps you can avoid multiple invocations to CreateObject by copying my approach.
BTW this is not well tested and I'm sure a regular Access VBA coder could improve the code.
You'll need to create an Access DB .accdb - in my example it is called in c:\a\tempdb.accdb, and you'll need to modify the other constant values.
Option Compare Database

Const TempDBFullName As String = "c:\a\tempdb.accdb"
Const RSAllName As String = "Updatedetailsall"
Const RSOneName As String = "Updatedetailsone"
Const JuniorMMMDFullName As String = "c:\a\junior.docx"
Const AdultMMMDFullName As String = "c:\a\adult.docx"
Const MailMergePDF As String = "c:\a\merged.pdf"
Sub mysub()

Dim wordApp As Word.Application ' Object if you are using late binding
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document ' Object
' MMMD = Mail Merge Main Document
Dim JuniorMMMD As Word.Document ' Object
Dim AdultMMMD As Word.Document ' Object
On Error GoTo problem

Set RSAll = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(" SELECT * FROM " & RSAllName)
With RSAll
  If .RecordCount > 0 Then ' first time through, Word (and probably Outlook too).
    ' You could probably also create your TempDB but I hven't done that here.
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    With wordApp
      .Visible = True
      ' Open your MMMDs once, at the beginning
      Set JuniorMMMD = .Documents.Open(JuniorMMMDFullName)
      Set AdultMMMD = .Documents.Open(AdultMMMDFullName)
    End With
  End If
  .MoveFirst ' probably not needed
  Do Until .EOF
    CurrentDb.Execute _
      " DELETE FROM " & RSOneName
    ' Insert into our temp database - helps solve locking problems
    ' You *could* insert the record directly into the temp db, using the following IN clause before the SELECT clause, and removing the TransferDatabase
    ' statement, but to do that, the table already has to exist with the correct structure, which we can avoid because TransferDatabase
    ' creates the structure. An Access person would probably know what's quickest if that's a concern.
    '
    CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT INTO " & RSOneName & _
      " SELECT * FROM " & RSAllName & _
      " WHERE ID = " & !ID
      
   ' That IN clause:
   ' " IN """ & TempDBFullName & """" & _

    DoCmd.TransferDatabase transfertype:=acExport, databasetype:="Microsoft Access", databasename:=TempDBFullName, objecttype:=acTable, Source:=RSOneName, Destination:=RSOneName
    
    If ![Membership Category] = "Junior Player" Or ![Membership Category] = "Junior Player (Sibling)" Then
      Call MergeOne(JuniorMMMD)
    Else
      Call MergeOne(AdultMMMD)
    End If
    .MoveNext
  Loop
  .Close
End With

problem: ' and final processing
Debug.Print Err.Description, Erl
If Not (wordApp Is Nothing) Then
  wordApp.Quit savechanges:=0 ' wdDoNotSaveChanges
  Set wordApp = Nothing
End If
If Not (RSAll Is Nothing) Then
  For Each x In CurrentDb.Recordsets
    If x.Name = RSAllName Then
      RSAll.Close
    End If
  Next
  Set RSAll = Nothing
End If

End Sub

Sub MergeOne(MMMD As Word.Document)
With MMMD
  With .MailMerge
    .MainDocumentType = 0 ' wdFormLetters
    .Destination = 0 ' wdSendToNewDocument
    .OpenDataSource _
      Name:=TempDBFullName, _
      sqlstatement:="SELECT * FROM [" & RSOneName & "]"
    .Execute
    .MainDocumentType = -1 ' wdNotAMergeDocument
  End With
  'Kill MailMergePDF
  With .Application.ActiveDocument
    .SaveAs2 FileName:=MailMergePDF, FileFormat:=17 'wdFormatPDF
    .Close savechanges:=0 ' wdDoNotSaveChanges
  End With
End With
End Sub

